# time not changing dynamically in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

if i remove final it gives error while using calendar variable and while using final time is not changing dynamically

```
final Calendar cal= new GregorianCalendar();
     Thread clock= new Thread(){
     public void run(){
      for (;;) {
        int am=cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        int hr=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int min=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
         if (am==0) {
             jtime_Label.setText(""+hr+":"+min+":"+sec+" AM");
         }else
         {
         jtime_Label.setText(""+hr+":"+min+":"+sec+" PM");
         }
         int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     int mon=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     date_label.setText(""+day+"-"+(mon+1)+"-"+year);

    }

     }


     };
     clock.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a GregorianCalendar object which would tahe the current time when it is created.

While processing to read the time from it, you do not change that time 
You need to change the time in your calendar cal during the processing.

I would suggest adding

```
cal.setTime(new Date());
```

or

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

In your loop inside your thread.

something like this

```
final Calendar cal= new GregorianCalendar();
Thread clock= new Thread(){
public void run(){
    for (;;) {
        //// add this line
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        /////
        int am=cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        int hr=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int min=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        if (am==0) {
            jtime_Label.setText(""+hr+":"+min+":"+sec+" AM");
        } else {
            jtime_Label.setText(""+hr+":"+min+":"+sec+" PM");
        }
        int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int mon=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        date_label.setText(""+day+"-"+(mon+1)+"-"+year);
        }
    }
};
clock.start();
```

Comment: its not helping. pls be more specific

Comment: thanq very much its running now

Comment: i have done that can you tell me the details why we have to do that

Answer (score 1):

> if i remove final it gives error while using calendar variable !!

It's not at all surprising , it will give the error because JLS specified so

> However, a local class can only access local variables that are
>   declared final

As [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28%29) say

```
public GregorianCalendar() //---> Default constructor
```

> Constructs a default GregorianCalendar using the current time in the
>   default time zone with the default locale

So it doesn't mean that if you are going to use this calendar Object after 10 min or after 20 min it will change the time , it will remain the same having time when the Object get created

if you want to create a timer then JTimer Probably help you out , but this is not the correct way to do it !!

Comment: can you please be more specific about the query